# Jersey ResourceFilter and spring

Tags: java, filter, jersey

I am using Jersey 1.17 and Jersey-Spring 1.8.

I am trying to get a jersey `ResourceFilter` to install correctly. I want this filter to be application-wide.

I have defined the ResourceFilter implementation as a bean in spring (defined in XML) and annotated it with the `@Provider` annotation.

```
@Provider
public class ContainerResourceFilterTest implements ResourceFilter
{
    public ContainerRequestFilter getRequestFilter()
    {
        return null;  //TODO
    }

    public ContainerResponseFilter getResponseFilter()
    {
        return null;  //TODO
    }
}
```

But it doesn't get hit when I send a request in.

If I use the `@ResourceFilters` annotation on a particular resource then it works as expected, but I don't want to do that on every single class.

How do I register a filter that is application wide?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own questions.

Doing some further reading of the jersey source code I have found that the @Provider annotation doesn't do anything for `ResourceFilterFactory` or `ContainerRequest/Response`. These can only be registered in one of the following 2 ways

- Using the META-INF/services
- Using the init params of the servlet, for example in web.xml

  ```
  <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ResourceFilters</param-name>
      <param-value>com.my.path.ResourceFilterFactory</param-value>
  </init-param>
  ```

Not sure why the code doesn't inspect the registered spring beans for @Providers that implement the appropriate interfaces.

Worth noting that registering a class that implements `ResourceFilter` does not work for either of the above methods. You must do it for `ResourceFilterFactory` and have that return `ResourceFilter` implementations.

The good news is once you have made jersey aware of the *classes* that need to be registered it calls into spring to provide those classes so auto-wiring etc works as per usual.

Answer (score 0):

Jersey doesn't scan the classpath for everything - ResourceFilters are one of the things it won't find automagickally. If you're using a [ResourceConfig](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html) class, register your ResourceFilter class:

```
@ApplicationPath("/myapp")
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public MyApplication() {
        packages(getClass().getPackage().toString());
        register(ContainerResourceFilterTest.class);
    }
}
```

Jersey will then scan that class for the filter interface, create an instance (all filters are singleton scope according to their docs) and insert it into the Jersey filter chain.